# Magento 2: Add custom code before closing head tag

Tags: magento2, layout, head

I am new to Magento.

I have some products in my Magento 2 website. I want to add some custom meta code before closing of head tag.

**Example**

```
if (page_id==1){
 some code 
}
if(page_id==2){
other code 
}
```

So in which `php` / `phtml` file have to add this code?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add your meta keywords or description in the product admin section under SEO Content tab.

Or if you want to add your code file in the add then you can add your static block or file in the head with `default.xml`. Below is an example to add a template file in the head file.

> /app/design/frontend/[vendor]/[theme]/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<referenceContainer name="head.additional">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom_head_file" template="Magento_Theme::custom_head.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

Add `custom_head.phtml` file to the below path with your conditional content described below.

> /app/design/frontend/[vendor]/[theme]/Magento_Theme/Templates/custom_head.phtml

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cmsPage = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Cms\Model\Page');

$page_id = $cmsPage->getId();

if ($page_id==1){
    //your code for page id 1
}
if($page_id==2){
    //your code for page id 2
}
```

**Hope it helps!**

Comment: but where is the if condition ? . I wan to insert different code on head for different page . so using page id i have to write if condition .

Comment: I've updated my code, please have a review.

Comment: thank you . I will check this

Comment: i'm looking for exactly "before closing head tag", but this solution only put the js to middle of the <head></head>, not right before closing head tag.

Comment: try to add after="-" in the block <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom_head_file" template="Magento_Theme::custom_head.phtml" after="-"/>

Answer (score 0):

copy below code in default.xml without `<body>` or find `head.additional` paste below block with create one file i.e : `headcontent.phtml` than add your php code in phtml file.

```
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="head.additional">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="helpout" template="Magento_Theme::headcontent.phtml"/>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

than create `headcontent.phtml` with your html code :

```
  $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $cmsPage = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Cms\Model\Page');

    $page_id = $cmsPage->getId();

   if (page_id==1){
     some code 
    }
    if(page_id==2){
    other code 
    }
```

Comment: but where is the if condition ? . I wan to insert different code on head for different page . so using page id i have to write if condition .

Comment: i update my code.

Comment: thank you . I will check this