# How to add js right before head tag end

Tags: magento2, javascript, head

I want to add js EXACTLY right before end of head tag 
I've try this solution, but it only put the js to middle of the head tag, not right before end of head tag
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/286655/70258 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to try the code in this way.

```
<referenceContainer name="head.additional">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom_head_file" template="Magento_Theme::custom_head.phtml" after="-"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, but this doesn't work, even if i try after="-".